# This application has encountered a lua error

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

I keep getting this error when i build for my android. the filenames are correct case and all, i dont see what the problem is. But when i take this code out it works so its somewhere here. any ideas?

```
local bg = display.newRect( 0, 0, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight )
bg:setFillColor( 255 )  -- white

local group = self.view

  local imageObj = {"box.png","box.png","box.png","box.png","box.png"}


  slide=slideView.new(imageObj,nill,0,50)   



-- all objects must be added to group (e.g. self.view)
group:insert( bg )
group:insert( slide )
```

Comment: It might be a red herring,  but nil  has one l and not two.  Also I presume you have required "slideView" higher up the code.  http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/slide-view

Comment: yea everythings included above it, it works in the simulator but not on the phone .......
also thank was too use to using NULL but that wasnt the error

Comment: id say double check again if the cases match have someone else read them for you second pair of eyes usally helps with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check again the box.png is are okey, btw use nil not nill.

Answer (score 0):

There are two leading causes of "It works in the simulator but not on device".  One is filenames with case problems the other are errors in your build.settings file which the simulator does not use.

Does slideView.new() take an array of images?